# R: Return two objects from apply function

Tags: r, list, apply

I loop the function **cutoff** over the dataframe **predictions** and the function correctly returns a new df (**correct_pred**) with two columns.
But I also want to safe the df **Percent** for each apply loop in a list. How can I do this? Now the function saves only the df for the last apply run.
I know the function is kinda messy. It used to be three separate function which were not supposed to be looped initially.
Please find the code and a generated input matrix below. Thanks in advance!

```
predictions <- data.frame(col1=runif(200), col2=runif(200))
test <- data.frame(rbinom(200,1,0.5))

cutoff <- function(model){
  Percent <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=200,ncol=19))
  for(i in 1:19){
    m = i*0.05
    Percent[,i] <- as.data.frame(ifelse(model <= m, 0, 1))
  }
  Percent <<- data.frame(Percent)
  
  validation <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=200,ncol=19))
  for(i in 1:19){
    validation[,i] <- Percent[,i] == test
  }
  validation <- data.frame(validation)
  
  correct_pred <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=19,ncol=1))
  for(i in 1:19){
    correct_pred[i,] <-(sum(validation[,i], na.rm = TRUE)/200)
  }
 correct_pred <<- data.frame(correct_pred)
}
correct_pred <<- as.data.frame(apply(predictions,2,cutoff))
correct_pred
```

Comment: make a list and return it

Comment: `test` object is not defined in the code provided so  `cutoff`  won't run. Anyways, the possible answers are 1) to define a lambda function inside the map/apply function that uses `<<-`  or return a list like @Bruno said.

Comment: I am sorry! I edited my code and it should work now. Could you please be elaborate what exactly you mean?

Comment: Since you are not using all numeric data types and use no column names, why are using data.frames. Simply use matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider keeping with matrices and vectors and compact your code with *apply* methods, like `sapply` and `colSums`, and have function return a list of multiple objects:

```r
set.seed(6521)

predictions <- replicate(2, runif(200))
test <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.5)

cutoff <- function(model){
  Percent <- sapply(1:19, function(i) ifelse(model <= i*0.05, 0, 1))
  validation <- Percent == test
  correct_pred <- colSums(validation, na.rm = TRUE)/200
  
  # RETURN NAMED LIST
  list(Percent = Percent, validation = validation, correct_pred = correct_pred)
}

output <- apply(predictions, 2, cutoff)
```

**Results**

```r
> str(output)
List of 2
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ Percent     : num [1:200, 1:19] 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ validation  : logi [1:200, 1:19] FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
  ..$ correct_pred: num [1:19] 0.545 0.525 0.52 0.51 0.51 0.525 0.54 0.57 0.55 0.535 ...
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ Percent     : num [1:200, 1:19] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ validation  : logi [1:200, 1:19] FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
  ..$ correct_pred: num [1:19] 0.54 0.53 0.51 0.5 0.515 0.515 0.53 0.53 0.51 0.5 ...

> head(output[[1]]$Percent)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
[6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

> head(output[[1]]$validation)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

> output[[1]]$correct_pred
 [1] 0.545 0.525 0.520 0.510 0.510 0.525 0.540 0.570 0.550 0.535 0.520 0.530 0.515 0.500 0.490 0.485 0.485 0.485 0.475
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!